# Dismiss Spinner on Server Side Validation Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

Performed extensive searches - could not find a solution.

When a user selects "submit" on a form, I'd like to display a spinner.  If there exists a validation error I'd like to dismiss the spinner so that the user can correct the errors on the form.  I know how to hook this when validating on the client.  But there are instances where I have to validate on the server.

In cases where there is a server side validation error is there a way to hook  `@Html.ValidationSummary` to call out a jQuery function?

I have to imagine this is a common scenario - just can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: If the form is a regular POST, the page will likely refresh very quickly. A spinner wouldn't stay on the page for long. Is this what you mean? The spinner would also disappear regardless of validation success. Can you mock up some visuals to show what you mean? It's not clear what you're attempting.

Comment: You are correct...  I wasn't catching it on the client.  Thanks Rowan.